# Merging Documents with OpenXML 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to insert some information and some pictures from a database into a Word Document.

I have created a Word document to serve as a template where I want to find and replace the keywords with the actual data and picture.

How do I open this template, replace the keywords, and put it into the new document. Then I need to re-open that template and do it again until everyone in the List is inside the new Word document.

```
//The template file exists, so open it and use it to set up the main Word document
using (WordprocessingDocument templatePackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateDocPath, false))
{
    //Read the template file
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(templatePackage.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    string tempString = docText;
    Regex regexText = new Regex("&lt;name&gt;");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, tnlCampers[0].FirstName + " " + tnlCampers[0].LastName);

    regexText = new Regex("&lt;address&gt;");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, tnlCampers[0].Address1 + " " + tnlCampers[0].Address2 + " " + tnlCampers[0].City + ", " + tnlCampers[0].State + " " + tnlCampers[0].ZipCode);

    regexText = new Regex("&lt;phone&gt;");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, tnlCampers[0].CellPhone);

    regexText = new Regex("&lt;email&gt;");
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, tnlCampers[0].Email);

    //Write to the newly created Word Document
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(package.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
```

But when I do a foreach loop on my tnlCampers list it throws an error because it's trying to copy the full document structure instead of just the body part. What can i do?

Comment: @TravisJ I've never really done anything like this before. So any help is appreciated. I'm not necessarily asking for the solution. Just a point in the right direction.

Comment: If you have visual studio, start by looking at their word 2007 template project. (there's also a word 2003 template project).  I think this should be a 'point in the right direction'

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Word Doc Generator](http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/) which is an utility to generate Word documents from templates using Visual Studio 2010 and Open XML 2.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you might also try our [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) component.

It has very user friendly and efficient support for mail merge. See [C# Word mail merge](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/c-sharp-vb-net-mail-merge) article and [customize mail merge](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Document/MailMerge/CustomizeMerge) sample.